# What does the OpenFlow Action OUTPUT do?

Tags: network-protocols

When I was reading some source code of Beacon, I got confused by the `OPAction_OUTPUT`.
The spec1.3 said

> Required Action: Output. The Output action forwards a packet to a
>   specified OpenFlow port (see 4.1). OpenFlow switches must support
>   forwarding to physical ports, switch-defined logical ports and the
>   required reserved ports (see 4.5).

But it confuse in two points:

- first, `The Output action forwards a *packet*`, but what this packet means? Does it means the OpenFlow `packet-out` containing Output Action? Or the packet contained in the **Data field** of OpenFlow `packet-out`.
- Second, what's the next? What will OpenFlow Switch do when they got a packet-out containing `OUTPUT` action?

Let me give an example: When OFcontroller got a packet-in, controller does(L2 switch):

```
 if dst in self.mac_to_port[dpid]:
     out_port = self.mac_to_port[dpid][dst]
 else:
     out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD
 actions = [datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]
 out = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPPacketOut(
     datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id, in_port=msg.in_port,
     actions=actions)
 datapath.send_msg(out) // send out the PacketOut containing output action
```

So, the question is:

- *What* is output by the action `OUTPUT` in this packet-out.
- What would OFSwitch do when it receives this packet-out on its port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mailing-list `OpenFlow-spec` answered the question. To make the question completed and help others, I post it here. Credit goes to Simon.

From Simon Horman :

> An OpenFlow Packet-Out message, which is interpreted as such, would be
>   received over an OpenFlow channel between the switch and a controller.
>   Traffic for the channel does not run through the OpenFlow pipeline
>   (OF1.3.2 section 6.3.1).
>
> Thus, it would be the packet contained in the data field of the
>   Packet-Out message which is processed by an Output action. This field
>   would be forwarded to the OpenFlow pipeline by the switch after it
>   receives the Packet-Out message via a channel.
>
> If the Packet-Out message is sent via a channel then it will be
>   decoded by the switch and the data field will be forwarded to the
>   OpenFlow pipleline as described above.
>
> If the Packet-Out message is not sent via a channel but rather just
>   happens to be a packet that contains data that looks like a Packet-Out
>   message then it will be handled directly by the OpenFlow pipeline
>   without any special processing.